# Jupyter notebook cannot open correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

everytime when I try to open jupyter notebook, it showed below error and cannot open:
could you let me know how to fix it?

```
[E 08:52:16.528 NotebookApp] Exception while loading config file C:\Users\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "i:\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 562, in _load_config_files
        config = loader.load_config()
      File "i:\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 457, in load_config
        self._read_file_as_dict()
      File "i:\python36\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 489, in _read_file_as_dict
        py3compat.execfile(conf_filename, namespace)
      File "i:\python36\lib\site-packages\ipython_genutils\py3compat.py", line 198, in execfile
        exec(compiler(f.read(), fname, 'exec'), glob, loc)
      File "C:\Users\kpu55\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py", line 86
        import webbrowser
        ^
    IndentationError: unexpected indent
[I 08:52:23.975 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32
[I 08:52:23.975 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 08:52:23.976 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
```

Comment: Remove the indentation on import web browser

Comment: this, you have a indentation... if it seems correct, use text editor like Sublime and convert all tabs to all spaces or all spaces to all tabs. Its what works for me when I get annoying indentation errors due to some whitespace or me using spaces somewhere instead of tabs.